# Solving NLODE with substitution

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation

I am trying to get a solution to a non-linear ODE, below is the code that works for my problem.

```
s = NDSolve[{y'''[x] + y[x]^2 y''[x] - y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x]} /. s], {x, 0, 1}]
```

1 Question how do you get the equations of the lines that are being plotted?
So say on x from 0 to 1 what is the equation of the line.

2 How do solve the same problem but using a substitution of u=dy/dx?

```
u''[x] + y[x]^2 u'[x] - u[x] == 0, u[0] == 0, u'[1] == 1
```

and we need to integrate to get the y value, not sure how to set that as a BC as well.

Thank you

Comment: equation of the line is `s` , it is InterpolatingFunction. type `s` to see it. You do not need to solve the problem again. The derivative is already here. You can either take derivative of the solution, of change `y` by `y,y'` in the NDSOlve itself, and NDSolve will return y' as well as y

Comment: I see that the solution is in s, and when I type s it gives me this InterpolatingFunction. I looked at the documentation, I do not see how to get a numeric equation of the line.

Comment: Right, I can get the value of y[x] from the first two lines of code. This is what I have, but does not seem to work, $NDSolve[{u''[x] + y[x]^2 u'[x] - u[x] == 0, u[0] == 0, 
  u'[1] == 1}, {x}, {x, 0, 1}]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get an exact solution with Mathematica,  but you may approximate it, for example with polynomials:

```
s = NDSolve[{y'''[x] + y[x]^2 y''[x] - y'[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[1]== 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}];
data = Table[{x, y[x] /. s[[1]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];
Manipulate[
 Column[{#, Show[ListPlot@data, Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], ImageSize -> 400]} &@ 
        Fit[data, Array[x^# &, n, 0], x]],
 {n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! An approximation is what I'm looking for. Just wasn't sure how to get the polynomial.